# Hibernate mysql json convert UTF8 string error

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate

For the extension of Hibernate types I use vladmihalcea / hibernate-types

```
@Entity
@TypeDef (
    name = "jsonb-node",
    typeClass = JsonStringType.class
)
public class Catalog {
...
@Type (type = "jsonb-node")
@Column (columnDefinition = "json")
public ArrayNode tags;
}
```

When converting a JSON object from MySQL to ArrayNode, UTF8 characters are not correctly converted

```
List <Catalog> catalog = em.createNativeQuery (
"select *"
+ "from Catalog c"
+ "where name regexp ('" + nameRegExpr + "*')"
+ "and isTemplate = true"
, Catalog.class
)
.getResultList ();
```

As a result, I get a string of the form
{"key": "??????????"}

Bytes of the string
7B226B6579223A223F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F3F227D

Source data in MySQL is stored correctly

[
{
"key": "новый"
}
]

Bytes
5b0a097b0a0909226b657922203a2022d0bdd0bed0b2d18bd0b9220a097d0a5d

How to correctly configure type conversion?

Comment: I had same problem with encoding. So first check your database encoding by executing query: `SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name = "schemaname";`. If it's UTF-8. Add this line in hibernate.cfg.xml on `hibernate.connection.url` property ending: `jdbc:mysql://localhost/myTableName?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8`. That helped me.

Comment: reading other fields of type varchar with utf8 characters occurs correctly